# AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400 in React Native

Tags: php, react-native, axios

I am using InfinityFree for hosting my mysql database and wanted to insert data into it from my React Native on button press to the server-side api but this "AXIOS ERROR [AxiosError: Request failed  with status code 400]" error shows up. Please help.

```
//.js

const insertData = async () => {  
    const firstName = 'John';
    const lastName = 'Doe'; 
  
    try {

      var postData = JSON.stringify({
        firstName,
        lastName,
      });
      
      let axiosConfig = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Accept": "application/json" 
        }
      };

      axios.post('http://mywebsite.great-site.net/insert.php', postData, axiosConfig)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
      })
 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error inserting data:', error);
    }
  };
```

Also, I have noticed that the error only shows up every other button press.

```
//insert.php in infinityfree domain file manager

<?php 
    $host = "sql213.infinityfree.com";
    $username = "if0_00000000";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "if0_34528777_mydatabase";
 
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

    // Check the connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    // Check if the request is a POST request
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
        // Get the data from the POST request (sent from React Native app) 
        $Acc_FirstName = $_POST["firstName"];
        $Acc_LastName = $_POST["lastName"]; 

        // Prepare the SQL query to insert the data into the database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `user`(`Acc_FirstName`, `Acc_LastName`) VALUES (?, ?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $Acc_FirstName, $Acc_LastName);

        // Execute the query and check for success
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            // Data inserted successfully
            $response["success"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Data inserted successfully";
        } else {
            // Failed to insert data
            $response["success"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "Failed to insert data: " . $conn->error;
        }

        // Close the prepared statement
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        // Invalid request method
        $response["success"] = false;
        $response["message3"] = "Invalid request method";
    }

    // Set the response headers to indicate JSON content type
    header(
        // "Content-Type: application/json"
        {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        });

    // Send the JSON response back to the React Native app
    echo json_encode($response);

    // Close the database connection
    $conn->close();
?>
```

This is my first time doing this so I am learning from other posts and asking chatgpt for help

Answer (score 1):

i don't have much experience on backend or php but 400 error means that the server was unable to process the request due to invalid information sent by the client.First make sure that the api is working with postman or Try changing Content-Type to application/json in axios header,

if the api is working on post man then simply extract the code from postman and use that

you can extract the code from postman by pressing </> icon on the right side and then select axios from dropdown

[image]